# Why does cmake create a 'source' directory in my build directory?

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, cmake

I am getting kind of frustrated with cmake, as I am trying to learn it and use it properly.

Here is my setup:

I have a directory called `~/project`. In this directory, I have:

- `build` directory
- `source` directory
- `includes` directory.
- `CMakeLists.txt` file.

The contents of this `CMakeLists.txt` file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(myProject)
subdirs(source)
```

I also have another `CMakeLists.txt` in `~/project/source`, and its content is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include_directories("~/project/includes")
add_executable(exec entry.cpp)
```

Now, I go into the build directory which is empty, and do `cmake ..`. This works fine. However I then see a 'source' directory get created as shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4l74bq9qr5rwug/Screenshot%202014-07-13%2013.42.12.png).

Why is this being created? I do not know what is going on. As I understand it, it should not be doing this, it should give me everything I see here, except for the 'source' directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your build directory, CMake re-creates the whole directory structure of your project. The rational is, to keep the project structure. Image a bigger project with several levels of subfolders and sources, libraries and tests scattered in a meaningful way. To run a test, you follow the structure where the test's source is located, just in the build directory instead of the source directory.

As your project, at least as far as CMake knows it, is only the `source` subdirectory, only this folder is created.

If you really have just the source project, I am not sure whether would be better to place the CMake project just inside `source`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, as far as I understood it, the build directory was simply supposed to house the executables once `make` was run. Why is it re-creating the entire source structure? I dont think it is supposed to do that...

Comment: It is supposed to do that, I just was not able to find a good source for this claim. If you have executables in `~/project` and in `~/project/source` they stay separated in `~/project/build` and `~/project/build/source`. As I said, if you only have sources in `sources` you may consider to make it the root directory of your CMake project.

Comment: So, let me rephrase. When I run `make` in the build directory, where will the executable file be created?

Comment: You can try yourself. I expect it to be in `~/project/build/source`.

Comment: The build directory will be populated with all sorts of intermediate files required by the build.  Object files, extra makefiles (or IDE project files), etc.  The whole point of building outside your source tree is to keep all this stuff separate.

Comment: You can adjust the binary location by doing this in your CMakeLists.txt file: `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(exec PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)` to put it in build/bin, for example.